# Evento onblur en dos divs

Tags: javascript, html

estoy elaborando una aplicacion para crear PDF, con PHP, Javascripts y MYSQL, es algo básico pero quiero mejorarla cada dia, el problema es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un panel de elementos, donde el usuario puede clickear en cualquiera de estos y mandarlo al área de edición, cuando se selecciona sobre el elemento le coloco un borde azul, (esto lo hago con tabindex="-1" en el div y el evento onfocus, todo bien hasta allí, pero ahora quiero presionar el botón color, y como tiene el evento onblur, pierde la selección apenas hago click en otro lado, como hago para solucionar eso?.

primera vez que hago este tipo de aplicaciones, y para cambiar las propiedades de los elementos lo hago por id y paso ese id por funciones js, es decir al momento de que el elemento pasa a la area de edicion inmediatamente se le asocia un id, no se si es la mejor manera de manejarlo, no se como hacen por ejemplo la aplicación "canvas" o editores online, gracias cualquiera solucion o recomendacion es bienvenida, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
function seleccionado(idElemento = null, nameElemento = null){

    let elementoSeleccionado = $('#'+idElemento);
    elementoSeleccionado.addClass('border border-primary');

    switch (nameElemento) {
        case 'card':

            alternarPanel(idElemento, nameElemento);
            
        break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function quitarSeleccion(id){
    let elementoSeleccionado = $('#'+id);
    elementoSeleccionado.removeClass('border border-primary');
    $('.nav-herramientas').html('');

}

function alternarPanel(idElemento, nameElemento){


    switch (nameElemento) {
        case 'card':

            content = ` 
            <div class="grupo d-flex justify-content-between">

                <div class="mr-1">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-default btn-herramienta" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Color</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header text-default">Colores predeterminados</h6>
                            <div class="grid-colores px-4 py-2">
                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorNegro">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorNegro.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorAzulOscuro">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorAzulOscuro.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorGris">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorGris.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorAzul">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorAzul.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorAzulClaro">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorAzulClaro.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorVerde">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorVerde.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorNaranja">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorNaranja.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="check-color">
                                        <input type="radio" name="colorCustom" onclick="clickColor('${idElemento}');" value="colorRojo">
                                        <img src="assets/img/imagesPDF/colorRojo.png" class="">
                                    </label>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                

                <div class="">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-default btn-herramienta"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                </div>

            </div>`;

        $('.nav-herramientas').html(content);
            
        break;
    
        default:
        break;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-8">

                        <div class="card shadow">

                            <div class="card-header py-0">

                                <div class="nav-herramientas d-flex justify-content-between">
                                   
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="card-body py-5 bg-secondary">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-10 p-5 shadow bg-white mx-auto" id="contenedorPDF">
                                        <div class="width: 100%;">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

El div "nav-herramientas" es donde pongo los botones de "color" y eliminar y eso lo alterno a medida que vaya cambiando de elemento.

y el contenedorPDF es la area de edición.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function seleccionado(idElemento = null, nameElemento = null){

    $(".contenedor").each(function( index ) {
        //index <= del array
        //$(this) <= boton actual
        $(this).removeClass('border border-primary');
        $('.nav-herramientas').html('');
    });

    let elementoSeleccionado = $('#'+idElemento);
    elementoSeleccionado.addClass('border border-primary');

    switch (nameElemento) {
        case 'card':

            alternarPanel(idElemento, nameElemento);
            
        break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Modifique la funcion seleccionado, ahora la puse a que se ejecutara con el evento onclick, entonces cuando se selecciona un div contenedor primero hago un each en todos los div con clase contenedor y  a estos les quito los bordes y luego le coloco los bordes al que se le dio click, no se si es una buena practica.